# Javascript Regex first character after occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a pager with this url: `news?page=1&f[0]=domain_access%3A3".`

I need a regex to replace the `page=1` with `page=2`

The 1 and 2 are variable, so I need to find `page=` + the first character after that.

How can I do that

@EDIT:

from the answers, I distilled

```
 var url = $('ul.pager .pager-next a').attr("href");
 var re = /page=(\d+)/i;
 var page = url.match(re);
 var splitPage = page[0].split("=");
 var pageNumber = parseInt(splitPage[1]);
 pageNumber += 1;
 var nextPagePart = 'page=' + pageNumber;
 var nextPageUrl = url.replace(re, nextPagePart);
 $('ul.pager .pager-next a').attr("href", nextPageUrl);
```

There might be a shorter approach ?

Comment: How about: `/page=(\d+)/`

Comment: Look at my edit. It's basically the same, just shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var url = 'news?page=1&f[0]=domain_access%3A3"';
var page = 2;
url = url.replace(/page=\d+/, 'page=' + page);
```

**EDIT**

To achieve what did in your edit:

```
var obj = $('ul.pager .pager-next a');
var url = obj.attr('href');
url = url.replace(/page=\d+/, 'page=' + (++url.match(/page=(\d+)/)[1]));
obj.attr('href', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only a page number and leave the rest You can try something like this:
`s/\(.*\)page=\d{1,}\(.*\)/\1number_to_replace\2/`

Comment: I first need to know the new number depending on the old one.